# Are elliptic curve irreducible?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, curves

Suppose we have a typical elliptic curve (smooth, projective curve with a distinguished point $\mathcal{O} = [0,1,0]$)  over some algebraically closed field $\overline{K}$
$$E: F(X,Y,Z) = Y^2Z + a_1XYZ + a_3YZ^2 - X^3 - a_2X^2Z - a_4XZ^2 - a_6Z^3 =0$$
is $F$ irreducible in $\overline{K}[X,Y,Z]$? I cant find anything definitive online.

Comment: An elliptic curve is a variety, hence irreducible, reduced, etc

Comment: What is your definition of elliptic curve? What you've written isn't a complete definition, since taking all the $a_i = 0$ yields $F = Y^2 Z$, which is reducible, but also doesn't define an elliptic curve.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn its also smooth, which takes care of what you brought up

Comment: @sqrt-3299 Again, what is your precise definition of elliptic curve? You should add this to your question. If $F$ is reducible, then the algebraic set it defines will not be smooth.

Comment: @ViktorVaughn okay thats interesting I didnt know that. Do you have an explanation for why, if F is reducible, then its not smooth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to get this off the unanswered list.

If $F$ is reducible (e.g. $F(x,y,z)=(x-y)(z-w)(y-z)$) then it cannot be smooth. The reason is the following nice observation:

> **Observation 1:** Let $X$ be a Noetherian regular connected scheme. Then, $X$ is integral.

*Proof:* We need to show that $X$ is irreducible and reduced. Since $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is regular for all $x$, and regular rings are integral (e.g see [1, Tag00NP]) we see that $X$ is clearly reduced. To see that it’s irreducible note that we can decompose $X$ into finitely many irreducible components $C_i$. Note then that if $X$ is not irreducible we must have that $C_i\cap C_j\ne \varnothing$ for some $i\ne j$ else then $\displaystyle X=\bigsqcup_i C_i$ which contradicts that $X$ is connected. But, let $x$ be a closed point of $C_i\cap C_j$ (for the $i,j$ where they intersect). Note then that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ cannot be integral since $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ contains $\eta_{C_i}$ which are distinct minimal primes. Thus, we arrive at a contradiction. Thus, $X$ is irreducible as desired. $\blacksquare$

This seems eminently useful if you know, a priori, that your hypersurface $E:=V(F)\subseteq \mathbb{P}^2_k$ is connected. But, again, this is actually automatic!

> **Observation 2:** Let $F\in k[x,y,z]$ be a non-zero homogenous polynomial. Then, $C:=V(F)\subseteq \mathbb{P}^2_k$ is connected.

*Proof:* There are several proofs of this fact. But, one is to note that if $n=\deg(F)$ then we have a short exact sequence

$$0\to \mathcal{O}(-n)\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2_k}\to i_\ast \mathcal{O}_C\to 0$$

where $i:C\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^2_k$ is the inclusion. From the LES in cohomology we see that we have an exact sequence

$$0\to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2_k}(\mathbb{P}^2_k)\to (i_\ast \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2_k})(\mathbb{P}^2_k)\to H^1(\mathbb{P}^2_k,\mathcal{O}(-n))$$

But, this last group is zero (e.g. see [1, Tag01XT]) and so we see that

$$k\cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2_k}(\mathbb{P}^2_k)\cong (i_\ast\mathcal{O}_C)(\mathbb{P}^2_k)=\mathcal{O}_C(C)$$

and so $\mathcal{O}_C(C)$ has no non-trivial idempotents, and so is connected. $\blacksquare$

***EDIT:*** This is somewhat tangential, but alternatively to **Observation 1** if you want to assume that your $E$ is a group, then it’s connected if and only if it’s irreducible (e.g. see Lemma 8 of [this](https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2019/11/19/classifying-one-dimensional-groups-ii/) blog post of mine).

**References:**

[1] Stacks project authors. *The Stacks Project*. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu